# Did the Dwarves do anything to help during the War of the Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, dwarves

In the LOTR series elves, men, hobbits and even eagles are a major help to the destruction of the ring and the saving of Middle-Earth. Dwarves didn't seem to be taking much part in this war.

Am I wrong or did the Dwarves keep to themselves During the War of the Ring?

Comment: I am 100% sure I have seen this answered in another question.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9730/what-are-the-main-reasons-the-elves-did-not-show-up-in-force-to-defeat-sauron

Comment: In a scene after Halbarad and the Dunedain meet up with our heroes, Legolas and Gimli have a conversation where Gimli wonders at the unexpected arrival of allies; when Gimli asks why the two of them didn't wish for their own kinsmen to join them, Legolas replies "They have no need to ride to war; war already marches on their own lands."

Comment: if you're going by the books, the elves didn't do much either. Except for Legolas and the two sons of Elrond, I'm pretty sure the elves weren't involved in the war either. Unless Thranduil's Mirkwood elves fought the same battles the dwarves of Erebor did

Comment: @childcat15 Both the Elves of Mirkwood and Lorien were attacked by Sauron's armies.  They did not march out like in the movies, but they were certainly involved.

Answer (score 22):

Other than Gimli, I assume?

The Dwarves of the Lonely Mountain came to the aid of Laketown against the forces of Sauron.

From Appendix B:

> At the same time as the great armies besieged Minas Tirith a host of the allies of Sauron that had long threatened the borders of King Brand crossed the River Carnen, and Brand was driven back to Dale. There he had the aid of the Dwarves of Erebor; and there was a great battle at the Mountain’s feet. It lasted three days, but in the end both King Brand and King Dáin Ironfoot were slain, and the Easterlings had the victory. But they could not take the Gate, and many, both Dwarves and Men, took refuge in Erebor, and there withstood a siege.

Other than that, there weren't significant populations of dwarves in the contested areas - the known dwarven realms besides the Lonely Mountain at the end of the Third Age are in Ered Luin, the Blue Mountains near the Shire, and in the Iron Hills north of the Lonely Mountain (although how many remained there after the Lonely Mountain was established once more was unknown).  Dwarves from the latter probably would've come to the aid of their brethren in the above battle if they had time.

Comment: It should be noted that this battle occurred at the same time as the Battle of the Morannon (and Frodo and Sam's presence at the Cracks of Doom). The Dwarves and Men may have only withstood the siege because of the destruction of the One Ring.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not military help as such, but Gloin and Gimli were sent to the Council of Elrond with warnings of the messenger from Mordor that visited Dain and to alert Bilbo that Sauron was searching for his ring and had heard of Hobbits.

> 'And so I have been sent at last by Dain to warn Bilbo that he is
>   sought by the Enemy, and to learn, if may be, why he desires this
>   ring, this least of rings.

I don't know if that qualifies directly as help during the War of the Ring but I personally take all three books in the LOTR trilogy to describe the War of the Ring

Answer (score -1):

I think the implication is that Dwarves are always engaged in warfare because of their greed. They battle among one another over riches and their kingdoms beneath the mountains. At one point in the movies, Legolas chides Gimli that his Dwarven folk are not well accustomed to making war. (that would imply the dwarves have experience at war)

Comment: How is being "not well accustomed to making war" implying that they have little or no experience at war? It's exactly the opposite.

Comment: I'm confused by the way you guys are using that phrase. "Not well accustomed" to something means you're not used to it and therefore have little or no experience with it